# Magento 2.3 settings in Admin are grayed out

Tags: magento2

I want to disable `Magento Review module` and modify the `etc/config.php`
'Magento_Review' => 0,
the review module did disable, but now a lot of the settings in admin interface are grayed out

How to restore changes and put it back to be able to edit settings in admin?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it's a configuration issue in either `config.php` or `env.php`

For myself, I found that I had a configuration issue in my `env.php` whereby I had 2 areas referencing different databases:

```
'db' => [
        'connection' => [
            'indexer' => [
                'host' => 'mysql',
                'dbname' => 'my_db_2',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'active' => '1',
                'persistent' => NULL,
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;'
            ],
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'mysql',
                'dbname' => 'my_db_1',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'active' => '1',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;'
            ]
        ],
        'table_prefix' => ''
    ],
```

Had my_db_1 in 1 and my_db_2 in the other. Upon matching these I ran:

```
php bin/magento app:config:import && \
php bin/magento setup:upgrade && \
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

And the configuration was no longer greyed out / disabled / unchangeable.